# Peano' s Systems

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, set-theory, definition, peano-axioms

Lets consider $(A,g,a_{0})$ , where $A$ is a set, $g$ is a function and $a_{0}$ is the first element of $A$. If $(A,g,a_{0})$ follows all the Peano's axioms, than we can find an isomorphism f between $(A,g,a_{0})$ and $(N,s,0)$. N is the set of natural numbers and s is the Peano s function. $f(a_{0})=0$ and $(f•g)(a)=(s•f)(a)$

My question is: shall g be equal to s? I will give an example

Lets consider A={1,3,5,7,9,11,...}
the set of odd numbers. Can i define g(1)=3, g(3)=5,...,Etc.?

It exists an isomorphism f between A and N. Can i say that $f:(A,g,a_{0}) \rightarrow(N,s,0)$ is an isomorphism of Peano's systems?

Comment: What version of set theory are you working in?

Comment: Actually is a generical question, so every set theory should be ok

Comment: Yes, you can use the set of odd numbers, but the number $1$ in the odd numbers corresponds to $0$, so $1+3$ in $A$ is $3..$ $3+3=5,$ $5\cdot 5=9.$ The real question is if there is any $(A,g,a_0)$ which is not such a "renaming" of the naturals.

Comment: Certainly, there exist non-standard models of the Peank axioms. Not sure about what that says about this question, but it seems related.

Comment: Can i say that for every infinite subset A of N exists f so that $f:A \rightarrow N$ is a Peano's System? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Depends on you define $g:A\to A.$ If you define $g(a)$ to be the "next" element of $A,$ then sure. But according to this, there are non-standard countable models Peano arithmetic, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic

Comment: Yes,  i had some confusion because my notes seemed to communicate that g should have been identical to s. In that case i should have  considered only subsets of N of the form A={x| x>n} where x is a natural number  @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ThomasAndrews OP is presumably referring to the (second order) Peano axioms, which have no nonstandard models. Not Peano arithmetic.